# Multiply value with unit in styled component

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I have a styled component like this:

```
export const Text = styled.div`
   padding: ${props => props.theme.padding * 2};
`;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because in my scenario `props.theme.padding` is 2rem (a string) and therefore cannot be multiplied with a number.

From my research I've seen a few conversations on the github page where people have requested a way to do this, but I can't find an actual clean solution anywhere. I will need to write code like this a lot. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I got around this by using `calc()`

```js
export const Text = styled.div`
   padding: calc(${props => props.theme.padding} * 2);
`;
```

Comment: It's a good method that works, but fundamentally this shifts the calculation from JavaScript to CSS which isn't always desired.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the number as prop and add the unit in the styled component

```
export const Text = styled.div`
   padding: ${props => parseFloat(props.theme.padding) * 2}rem; // padding is a float here 
`;
```

or you should extract the number, which i dont recommend much due to performance implication

```
const valueFromUnit = x => parseFloat(x.match(/\d+/g));

export const Text = styled.div`
   padding: ${props => valueFromUnit(props.theme.padding) * 2}rem;
`;
```

Comment: The issue is that the value is theme-able so could be rem/px/em. Therefore it isn't DRY or safe to hardcode the unit on every usage. I've come from SCSS where multiplications like this are a basic necessity. I'm very surprised there's nothing built into styled components or polished to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with a pretty simple utility function:

```js
// utils.js
export const unitMultiplier = (value) => (quotient) => {
  const num = parseFloat(value);
  const unit = value.replace(num.toString(), "");

  return num * quotient + unit;
};
```

You could just include this in your project like so:

```js
import { unitMultiplier } from "~/utils";

export const Text = styled.div`
   padding: ${props => unitMultiplier(props.theme.padding)(2)};
`;
```

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that there is a library that is really good at this sort of thing: https://polished.js.org/docs/#math